# Ckeditor and using $_POST to insert into Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ckeditor

Alright, so I have been banging my head for hours on this. Time to turn to the pros.

I am using jquery to post the serialized form.

I have ckeditor on a page, according to their [instruction](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) all I have to do is set the post to a variable and it will work. Well it doesn't. $_POST['TEXTAREA_NAME'] is empty.

alright, no problem. I can just use jquery to append the data to the textarea before the post takes place. now all i get is \r\n.

help please, what is the best way to get the data from ckeditor to mysql?

Text are:

```
<textarea id="content" name="content"><?php if($_GET['act'] == "edit"){ echo getDigestInfo($articleID, "content"); } ?></textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
function saveNew(){
            $.post("crud/man-digest.php?act=add", $("#edit-content-form").serialize(),
                function(data){
                    $("form .message").append(data);
                }
                ,"json"
            );
        }
```

PHP:

```
$articleID = intval($_POST['id']);
                    // Perform Update
                    $article_title = mysql_prep($_POST['title']);
                    $article_content = mysql_prep($_POST['content']);
                    $article_system = mysql_prep($_POST['system']);
                    $article_updated = mysql_prep($_POST['updated']);
                    $article_datecreated = $_POST['datecreated'];
                    $query = "UPDATE techdigest SET 
                                title = '{$article_title}', 
                                content = '{$article_content}',
                                lastupdate = CURDATE(),
                                system = '{$article_system}',
                                datecreated = DATE('{$article_datecreated}')
                                WHERE id = {$articleID}";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Feel pretty dumb here.

figured it out.

when updating the textarea it is best to use .html() instead of .append()

works so far!

*~~~~wow,*

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax post gets the content from the wrong textarea. It should be:

```
$.post("crud/man-digest.php?act=add", $("#content").serialize(),
```

Comment: as mentioned above, I'm serializing the form, not just the field. I suppose I should have clarified that. anyway found the problem, need to use .html and not .append to update text area.