# How to store CKEditor data into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I have CKEditor and want to send its data to the server in order to store it in MySQL. I am able to send source code (data) of CKEditor to the server with jQuery Ajax but when I try to execute my SQL query in order to store it in the database the insert command gives error. I think the main problem here is that CKEditor data contains new lines in it. How to solve this problem?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430262/ckeditor-and-using-post-to-insert-into-mysql) question similar to mine, but when I tried it and it didn't work for me. And I didn't understand what does `mysql_prep` function do, because it is not standard PHP function.

**update 1**

The code for the HTML form is following:

```
$("#save").click(function(){
    var data = $( '#editor1' ).val();                                        
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"save.php",
        data: "editor1="+data,
        timeout:15000, 
        error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert("ERROR");                            
        },
        success:function(response){
          alert("Success: "+response);
        }
    });                           
})
```

And the save.php has following codes:

```
<?php
   include '../config.php'; //connecting to DB 
   $title='news 1'; $author=1; $date="2011/08/08"; $categories='1,2,3';     
   $short_text=$_POST['editor1']; $full_text=$_POST['editor1'];    
   $sql=sprintf('insert into news values(null,"%s",%d,"%s","%s","%s","%s")',$title,$author,$date,$short_text,$full_text,$categories);
   mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in $sql");
?>
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to insert.

Comment: Have added necessary source codes

Comment: What does the MySQL error say? And you should be escaping the code

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, MySQL likes single quotes, not double.

Answer (score 0):

[Little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) says that you are *very* vulnerable to SQL Injection.  The simplest way to both mitigate SQL injection **and** fix any issues with newlines is to use prepared statements.  At the very least you need to be escaping your input, which would also fix issues with newlines.  You could use `mysql_real_escape_string`, except of course that was deprecated years ago, so for recent work you should at least be using the mysqli* functions (and then use prepared queries while you are at it).

Answer (score -1):

-Use this

> $short_text= htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor1']);

Comment: htmlspecialcharacters won't fix it: it won't actually remove the newlines, and it will completely kill the purpose of the ckeditor.  ckeditor is a wysiwyg editor that is designed to build HTML code to be outputted to a web page.  If you then run it through htmlspecialchars, all that HTML will no longer be able to be outputted to a webpage.